# Copy and Paste values vba with criteria

Tags: vba

I want to re-evaluate (copy and paste) formula values depending on other formula values in vba

Here is my example:

D2 contains a drop down list with values 1, 2 and 3.

IF D2=2 (base case) then variable1=10. For this value the result given in G2 equals to 100

IF D2=1 (low)           then variable1=5.    For this value the result given in G2 equals to 80

IF D2=3 (High)           then variable1=5.    For this value the result given in G2 equals to 120

Note that G2 contains the result of my budget as a formula. This comes from another sheet

I want to re-evaluate (copy and paste) these values in cells F2 and H2. I run the following code, but I take the same value 100 as this is in cell G2

Comment: Hi & welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you can update your question to better help us help you. You'll find lots of help here with fixing broken code, but very few people willing to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

want to re-evaluate (copy and paste) formula values depending on other formula values in vba

Here is my example:

D2 contains a drop down list with values 1, 2 and 3.

IF D2=2 (base case) then variable1=10. For this value the result given in G2 equals to 100

IF D2=1 (low) then variable1=5. For this value the result given in G2 equals to 80

IF D2=3 (High) then variable1=5. For this value the result given in G2 equals to 120

Note that G2 contains the result of my budget as a formula. This comes from another sheet

I want to re-evaluate (copy and paste) these values in cells F2 and H2. I run the following code, but I take the same value 100 as this is in cell G2

Here is my code

Range("D2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 2

```
Range("G2").Select

Selection.Copy

Range("F2").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _

    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Range("D2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 3

```
Range("G2").Select

Selection.Copy

Range("H2").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _

    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Range("D2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 1

End Sub